# PHP/SQL/WHILE none repeat

Tags: php, html, sql

```
function editJedz($session,$id){
    $query = mysqli_query($this->handle,"SELECT * FROM posilki WHERE opiekun='".intval($session)."' ") or die (mysqli_error($this->handle));
    $nazwa = mysqli_query($this->handle,"SELECT * FROM ceny");
    $czytaj='';
    $i=1;
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $czytaj .= '<br/>'.$i.$rows['Imie'].' '.$rows['Nazwisko'];
        while($check= mysqli_fetch_array($nazwa)){
            $czytaj.= '<input type="checkbox" id="hrm" name="hrm" />'.$rows['Imie'];
        }
        $check=0;
        $i++;
    }
    return '<form action="?view=edit?action=editJedz" method="POST">'
    .$czytaj.'<input type="submit" value="Zatwierdz">'.
    '</form>';
}
```

Now the code works now:

Name [x] Diner [x] HotDog
Next Name NONE CHECK and immediately submit

How does he want to work:
Name [x]Diner [X]HotDog

NextName [x]Diner [X]HotDog

Submit

IMG : http://roshedweb.pl/Pliki/work.php

Comment: Sorry, but could you make the question a bit more clearer? Also provide us with some info which information is in the table posilki?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do, what is the problem, and what have you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your problem is that you are missing the section with the checkboxes in the 2nd line (2nd name). The reason is that you have to reset the pointer in your ceny table first, otherwise the mysqli_fetch_array($nazwa) will not return any data. Apart from that, I dont't think you want the $rows['Imie'] after your checkbox.

tip: fetch the data from your ceny table into an array and use that in your loop.

try something like

```
function editJedz($session,$id){
    $query = mysqli_query($this->handle,"SELECT * FROM posilki WHERE opiekun='".intval($session)."' ") or die (mysqli_error($this->handle));
    $nazwa_res = mysqli_query($this->handle,"SELECT * FROM ceny");
    $nazwa = $nazwa_res->fetch_all();
    $czytaj='';
    $i=1;
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $czytaj .= '<br/>'.$i.$rows['Imie'].' '.$rows['Nazwisko'];
        foreach ($nazwa as $idx => $n) {
            $czytaj.= '<input type="checkbox" id="hrm'.$idx.'" name="hrm'.$idx.'" />'.$n['...'];
        }
        $check=0;
        $i++;
    }
    return '<form action="?view=edit?action=editJedz" method="POST">'.
           $czytaj.'<input type="submit" value="Zatwierdz">'.
           '</form>';
}
```

Comment: Now i take to $n name of rekord like this ($n['Nazwa']) where Nazwa is Name in the mysql.
PHP result 
Undefined index: Nazwa in E:\xampp\htdocs\jadalnia\engine\edit.php on line 42